# Stop Program from closing CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, console-application

I am trying to use the SetConsoleCtrlHandler function but it's not working like i want it to, i want stop the Program from Closing when i press the X but i dont know how to COMPLETELY overwrite the CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:

```
#include <myHead.h> //selfmade header

BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(DWORD dwCtrlType){
    switch(dwCtrlType)
    {
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
        {
            cout << "Closing...";
            getch();                    //should wait for a character after calling the CLOSE_EVENT
            return true;
        }
    default:
            return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine,true);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not possible.  The callback is just there to allow you to clean up.